# how to set/change the font style in database?

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-design

This question may be duplicate with another but my question is this.

I want to set or change the font style in header of table (like hindi font or any other) of database. I am using sql server 2008 on my system. I have no idea to changed the font (like kruti dev 010 or dev lys 010 or etc). I want some headers of the table in english and some other in hindi language.

I hope this information will be complete to understand.

please reply if any one have some ideas about such kind of things.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using SQL, you can use any characters almost: that is, the [`sysname`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191240%28SQL.100%29.aspx) datatype which is `nvarchar(128)`

Example (copied Hindi and Urdu text from Wikipedia)

```
CREATE TABLE मानक (
    اردو int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,  --SQL editor reads *only* the column name right to left
    foobar int NULL
    );
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM sys.objects O ORDER BY O.create_date DESC;
DROP TABLE मानक;
```

If you mean in the GUI, then this should be Windows locale dependent.

If you mean the GUI designers, then frankly I don't know because I use raw SQL.

If you mean the actual SQL language, then it is English

Edit: Under Tools.. Options, you can select fonts. This may be what you want:

[image]

Comment: as you shown how I can write मानक in table header. Is there any option to change the font in database tools or any other way

Comment: @GhostAnswer: Added more. If this doesn't help, then you need to explain more